# Trying to run a groovy script to populate a string's description, but the script returns no output, what could be the reason?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters

I'd like to configure a choice parameter in Jenkins.

The parameter I'd like to configure is called CIDR.

I tried using "Extended choice parameter" plugin but to no avail.

What I'm trying to do, is to let the user manually insert the chosen CIDR, considering the CIDRs which are already in use -> I want to run a groovy script to populate the string description with CIDRs which are already in use.

In order to list the already in use CIDRs, I wrote the following Groovy code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
def p = ['/usr/local/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs'].execute() | 'grep CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,"'].execute()
p.waitFor()
println p.text
```

The script runs properly in terminal:

```
itai@Itais-MacBook-Pro ~ -  $ groovy cidrs.groovy
172.31.0.0/16
172.51.0.0/16
172.51.0.0/16
```

I even accepted a suspicious signature in Jenkins in-script approvals to allow the script to run.

But when I insert it to the Groovy script section of the string description and run the "build the job with parameters", the string dropdown stays empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the parameter kept being empty is that as it seems, the "Extended Choice Parameter" plugin expects the output to be an array.

Changing the script to the following code solved the issue:

```
#!/opt/groovy-2.4.12/bin/groovy
def p = ['/usr/bin/aws', 'ec2', 'describe-vpcs'].execute() | 'grep CidrBlock'.execute() | ['awk', '{print $2}'].execute() | ['tr', '-d', '"\\"\\|,"'].execute()
p.waitFor()
def output = []
p.text.eachLine { line ->
    output << line
}

output.each {
    println it
}
```

Now the parameter is populated with the available CIDRs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks trivial issue. Try below.

**Change From :**

```
println p.text
```

**To:**

```
return p.text
```